# How to ADD a CONSTRAINT NAME to an already EXISTING CONSTRAINT

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Is there a way to give names to already existing constraints? 

for example :

```
create table employee (emp_id number(10),emp_name varchar2(20),
dept_id number(10),foreign key(dept_id) references department(dept_id));
```

In the above query I haven't named the foreign key constraint so after the creation of the table can I give a name to it also can the foreign key constraint be dropped without dropping the column??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can rename a constraint like this:
`alter table t rename constraint old_name to new_name`

Edit: I've forgotten about the second question. Yes you can drop a constraint without dropping the column. If you do not know the name of the constraint you can find it in `user_constraints` table like this:

`select constraint_name
    from user_constraints
    where table_name = 'your_table'
    and constraint_type ='R'`

Answer (score 2):

For the second part,  yes you can drop the foreign key constraint.

Comment: without a name and without having to drop the column?

Comment: Alter table table_name drop constraint constraint_name

Comment: No, You can't drop it when you haven't specified any name unless you know the system specified constraint name.